# Ruby case multiple conditions with and

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got below `case` condition which works well.

```
case params[:event_type]
when 'publish'
  StoreActivityWorker.perform_async(params)
when 'delete'
  DeleteActivityWorker.perform_async(params)
end
```

But I want to add another conditions to each `when` - `name == %w[Text Video Audio]` so the code should be like:

```
case params[:event_type]
when 'publish' && name == %w[Text Video Audio]
  StoreActivityWorker.perform_async(params)
when 'delete' && name == %w[Text Video Audio]
  DeleteActivityWorker.perform_async(params)
end
```

but it won't work, it shows `false` every time.

name is just:

```
params.dig('entity', 'relationships', 'item_type', 'data', 'name')
```

Comment: `name == %w[Text Video Audio]` you mean when `name` equal to an array with these three items, or when `name` is equal one of the array elements?

Comment: is equal one of the array elements

Comment: Then you check it the wrong way, use `name.in?(%w[Text Video Audio])`

Answer (score 2):

Currently you're checking if

```
('publish' && name == %w[Text Video Audio]) === params[:event_type]
```

or if

```
('delete' && name == %w[Text Video Audio]) === params[:event_type]
```

The left side of `===` can be either `true` or `false` and I don't think `params[:event_type]` is going to be either of those two values, so neither of your two cases are going to be executed.

What you probably want is something like:

```
if name == %w[Text Video Audio]
  case params[:event_type]
  when 'publish'
    StoreActivityWorker.perform_async(params)
  when 'delete'
    DeleteActivityWorker.perform_async(params)
  end
end
```

Even that seems a bit off since you're checking if `name` is equal to `%w[Text Video Audio]` which I don't think is going to be the case. Perhaps you want:

```
%w[Text Video Audio].include?(name)
```

A nested case inside of an if statement is also not the best option. I might suggest a guard clause but without knowing the entire method it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `'publish' && name == %w[Text Video Audio]` does not make sense. Remember that `&&` is a shortcut operator: `(E1) && (E2)` evaluates `E1`, and if the result is falsy, returns this value (i.e. `nil` or `false`), **without even looking at `E2`**. If E1 is trueish, it evaluates and returns E2. In your case, `'publish'` is trueish, and hence E2 is returned.

Your E2 is

```
name == %w[Text Video Audio]
```

and this expression evaluates to either be `true` or `false`, and neither can match your `params[:event_type]`, because the event type is likely not `true`nor `false`, but a string, and therefore the condition does not fire.

Comment: "...if the result is not falsy, returns this value, without even looking at E2..." <-- that would only be the case for the `||` operator. `&&` can only shortcut once it has found a falsy value and knowns that the whole expression will be falsy. In your answer, you seem to be mixing up the semantics for `||` and `&&` throughout.

Comment: You are so right!!! I completely explained it the other way round. Fixed it. Please check, for the safe side.